# "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in Swift 1.2

Tags: swift, xcode6.3

I have an Objective C class `SomeClass` which has a nullable property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) __nullable ClassA* clsAProperty;
```

In a Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta 3) file, I attempt to assign the property to a nullable property:

```
private var clsAProperty : ClassA?
...
self.clsAProperty = SomeClass.someInstance().clsAProperty as ClassA?
```

This code is crashing with the following message:

> Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Everything works as expected when compiled under Xcode 6.2.

Is this a bug, or am I missing anything? What optional is the runtime attempting to unwrap, when both are supposed to optional?

Comment: There has been some change with respect to Objective-C and Nullability in XCode 6.3, check this link - https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: @rshankar I see nothing there to suggest a change in this regard from previous Swift iterations.

Comment: Is it possible that `SomeClass.someInstance()` is `nil` or is that just placeholder code?

Comment: @sbooth It's a placeholder code, and the instance is not nil. `clsAProperty` is, but that's acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an Xcode bug. Later betas fixed the issue.